# Expats alias, but not meta.expats?

Tags: feature-request

We can use the alias expats.stackexchange.com to get to expatriates.stackexchange.com.

However, meta.expats.stackexchange.com doens't work. Any chance we can get this alias added as well?

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut is there for two reasons really:

- Easier to tell folks how to get to the site via word-of-mouth, expats is easier to remember
- Shortcut to type when browser completion doesn't know what you mean by 'expa' yet

There's links to meta on the main site right from the site switcher, so adding another alias just for meta has a *very* narrow use case, and just becomes another exceptional thing in server configs to maintain.

If it were something simple that I didn't have to ask someone else to do I'd probably just do it, but given that it takes a dev to do and document and such, I don't think it's really worth it.

Comment: /shakes fist! But I'm lazy! ;) Plus it's such a habit to type expats.sta.. that I do the same for meta. Ah well.